# Как оставить комментарий на стене пользователя через vk_api на Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот, комментарии

Прочитав по нескольку раз официальную документацию (https://vk.com/dev/wall.createComment и всё что связано с wall.get), так и не понял, как оставить комментарий от имени сообщества на странице пользователя через vk_api на Python. Надеюсь на помощь в данном вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример из документации https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
import vk_api

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('+71234567890', 'mypassword')
vk_session.auth()

vk = vk_session.get_api()

print(vk.wall.post(message='Hello world!'))
```

У меня работает.